# SharePoint Designer Workflow Limitations

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, email

Is there any limitation in the SharePoint designer workflow - "Send an email" action?

Limitations like # of characters or # of recipients.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Designer 2010​ has a limitation when trying to implement a workflow action to send an email to multiple users based from lookup from a people picker control that accepts more than one user.  By default the email action will only email to the first user and will not detect multiple users.

The exact answer to your questions lies [here](http://www.mpspartners.com/2012/05/spdesigner2010workflowsendingemailstomultipleusersfromasinglepeoplepickerfield/)

Comment: Actually, I have a field where I am having around 500 email addresses and I like to use this field to send email notification. It seems that few people are not getting emails even the email addresses are valid.

Comment: We ran into this today.  From our testing, it appears that the email send action is limited to 100 email addresses per field (To, bcc, etc.).

Comment: We ran into a similar issue - is this documented anywhere? 

The only thing I've found for sp2013 is the 100 limit on "Workflow timer batch size" listed here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/software-boundaries-and-limits